# android get cell towers for all providers

Tags: android, cell, neighbours

I used getNeighboringCellInfo() but it returns one entry only, seems to be the cell of my current provider.. how to get cell towers from all providers ?

Based on this question:
[How can I get cell tower data for all cell towers from all network providers in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9796946/1862806)

Seems issue not possible, but can someone explain more why not possible even if roaming enabled?

my current location egypt, with providers etisalat, vodafone, mobinil, if this will help to get more specific info ..

thanks